# Using Electron, how can I make a BrowserView within a BrowserWindow draggable?

Tags: electron

I would like to have a `BrowserView` embedded within my main `BrowserWindow` that could be dragged around within the confines of the `BrowserWindow`. However, when I use the css `-webkit-app-region: drag`, dragging the `BrowserView` actually moves the whole `BrowserWindow` around. How can I achieve my goal ?

Here is a reproduction setup :

src/main.js :

```js
import * as path from 'path';
import { app, BrowserView, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';
    
const baseDir = app.getAppPath()
   
app.on("ready", async () => {
    
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: true,
        },
        frame: false
    });
    
    mainWindow.setMenu(null);
    mainWindow.maximize();
    mainWindow.on('closed', () => app.quit())
    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(baseDir, "src/main.html"));
   
    const view = new BrowserView({
        webPreferences: {
            sandbox: false,
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
        },
    })
    view.webContents.loadFile(path.join(baseDir, 'src/window.html'));
    view.setBounds({
        x: 200,
        y: 200,
        width: 1000,
        height: 500,
    })
    
    mainWindow.addBrowserView(view);
});
```

src/main.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    
<html>
    
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
    
<body style="background-color: #666;"></body>
    
</html>
```

src/window.html :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    
<html>
   
<head>
    <title>Embeded</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
   
<body class="dragWindow" style="background-color: #888;"></body>
    
</html>
```

src/style.css :

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  
    -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
}
    
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
    
.dragWindow {
    -webkit-app-region: drag; 
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
    user-select: none;
}
```

Edit : I tried using a script to communicate drag events from the `BrowserView` to the `main process`, and move the `BrowserView` around from the `main process`, but the result, while working, is super slow, I assume due to the lag of the communication between the processes. When moving the mouse too fast, it simply exits the `BrowserView` and the dragging stops while staying in the "dragged" state. I would much prefer if an Electron native solution existed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find some cool informations in this issue: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/32751#issuecomment-1030484112

They talk about private APIs exposed by electron where you could probably find a solution.

Also the author of the issue is trying to find a similar solution as you in order to react to events/inputs in the `BrowserView`.

Comment: Yeah, it seems right now my issue has no solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import * as path from 'path';
import { app, BrowserView, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } from 'electron';

const baseDir = app.getAppPath();

app.on('ready', async () => {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: true,
    },
    frame: false,
  });

  mainWindow.setMenu(null);
  mainWindow.maximize();
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => app.quit());
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(baseDir, 'src/main.html'));

  const view = new BrowserView({
    webPreferences: {
      sandbox: false,
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
    },
  });

  view.webContents.loadFile(path.join(baseDir, 'src/window.html'));
  view.setBounds({
    x: 200,
    y: 200,
    width: 1000,
    height: 500,
  });

  mainWindow.addBrowserView(view);

  let isDragging = false; // Track the dragging state
  let initialMouseX, initialMouseY; // Track the initial mouse position
  let initialViewX, initialViewY; // Track the initial view position

  ipcMain.on('start-drag', () => {
    isDragging = true;
  });

  ipcMain.on('stop-drag', () => {
    isDragging = false;
  });

  ipcMain.on('drag', (event, { deltaX, deltaY }) => {
    if (isDragging) {
      // Calculate the new view position based on mouse movement
      const newX = initialViewX + deltaX;
      const newY = initialViewY + deltaY;
      view.setBounds({ x: newX, y: newY, width: 1000, height: 500 });
    }
  });

  view.webContents.on('dom-ready', () => {
    view.webContents.insertCSS(`
      .dragWindow {
        -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
      }
    `);

    view.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
      let isDragging = false;
      let startX, startY;

      document.querySelector('.dragWindow').addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
        isDragging = true;
        startX = e.clientX;
        startY = e.clientY;
        ipcRenderer.send('start-drag');
      });

      document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
        if (isDragging) {
          const deltaX = e.clientX - startX;
          const deltaY = e.clientY - startY;
          ipcRenderer.send('drag', { deltaX, deltaY });
          startX = e.clientX;
          startY = e.clientY;
        }
      });

      document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
        isDragging = false;
        ipcRenderer.send('stop-drag');
      });
    `);
  });
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I said I tried in the second part of my post. It does not work as it is slow as hell and jittery.